# Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit screen tearing

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, screen, tearing

Hardware:

- NVidia GTX 780
- I7 4770k
- 16 gb RAM
- 1x 128gb SSD + 2tb HDD + 1tb HDD

Software:

- Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.
- Latest NVidia Driver.

Issue:

- Whenever I watch a youtube video or a movie(Sometimes even when dragging a window). There's some heavy screen tearing in fast paced parts. But when I play a game 'Minecraft' for example I get a flawless 600 fps without issues. I've tried everything I can think of, but I can't seem to find a solution. Sync to VBlank enabled or disabled seems to make no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Could you add a number to "latest NVidia driver" and how did you install it?